# How to control that the method on the server returns HttpStatus in Angular4 ?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have method in server, which return List of data or HttpStatus

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object get(
        if(true) 
             return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
        else 
             return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

I want to control value of return from server, when returns HttpStatus throw somehow message, but if return list then give back data to component.

```
@Injectable()
export class HandlerService {
  private testUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/test';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public getTasks(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.testUrl);
  ]);
  }
}
```

I use HttpClient from angular/common/http, I don't know how to control this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the subscription:

```
this.handlerService.getTasks().subscribe(res => {}, err => {});
```

Note the last function with `err`.

Or you can do this at the service level:

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
public getTasks(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.testUrl).pipe(catchError(err => {}));
}
```

Comment: err haves HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND? If yes, how I use this, How can I do something depending on the error?

Comment: Debug in one of the `err` functions I provided. That info is present.

Comment: How can I tell if it's a HttpStatus or a connection error?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse

Look at the response `statusText` or `status` property.

Answer (score 0):

As @bc1105 said, you can do it in subscription or in service inside the callback **err** by the statement

```
let status = error.status;
```

In this way the value is saved.